# How to return jsonify object and render template parallel in Flask

Tags: flask, jwt

I want use the following login function. After JWT token is saved in cookies , I want to redirect to user home.

```
@app.route("/login", methods=['GET','POST'])
def login():
    signInform = LoginForm()
    examForm = PersonExamForm()
    online_users = mongo.db.users.find({"online": True})
    try:
        render_template('login.html', title = 'Login', form =signInform) db_cm.find_one({'username':signInform.username.data}) 
        if auth != None:
            print(signInform.password.data == auth['password'])
            if signInform.password.data == auth['password']:       
               access_token = create_access_token(identity=auth['username'], expires_delta=datetime.timedelta(minutes=1), user_claims=None, headers=None)
               refresh_token =create_refresh_token(identity=auth['username'], expires_delta=datetime.timedelta(minutes=1), user_claims=None, headers=None)
            # Set the JWT cookies in the response                
               resp = jsonify({'login': True})
               set_access_cookies(resp, access_token)
               set_refresh_cookies(resp, refresh_token)               
               return resp,200, render_template('home.html', posts = sample_posts, online_users=online_users)
```

It doesn't work, I get an error message:

> ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1) 
>   `127.0.0.1 - - [28/Nov/2019 13:37:48] "POST /login HTTP/1.1" 500 -
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "C:\Users\.virtualenvs\Test_Projects-7jm6kxsT\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2463, in __call__
>       return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
>     File "C:\Users\.virtualenvs\Test_Projects-7jm6kxsT\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2449, in wsgi_app
>       response = self.handle_exception(e)
>     File "C:\Users\.virtualenvs\Test_Projects-7jm6kxsT\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1866, in handle_exception
>       reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
>     File "C:\Users\.virtualenvs\Test_Projects-7jm6kxsT\lib\site-packages\flask\_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
>       raise value
>     File "C:\Users\.virtualenvs\Test_Projects-7jm6kxsT\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2446, in wsgi_app
>       response = self.full_dispatch_request()
>     File "C:\Users\.virtualenvs\Test_Projects-7jm6kxsT\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1952, in full_dispatch_request
>       return self.finalize_request(rv)
>     File "C:\Users\.virtualenvs\Test_Projects-7jm6kxsT\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1967, in finalize_request
>       response = self.make_response(rv)
>     File "C:\Users\.virtualenvs\Test_Projects-7jm6kxsT\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2142, in make_response
>       rv.headers.extend(headers)
>     File "C:\Users\.virtualenvs\Test_Projects-7jm6kxsT\lib\site-packages\werkzeug\datastructures.py", line 1091, in extend
>       for key, value in iterable:
>   ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)
>   127.0.0.1 - - [28/Nov/2019 13:37:48] "GET /login?__debugger__=yes&cmd=resource&f=style.css HTTP/1.1" 200 -
>   127.0.0.1 - - [28/Nov/2019 13:37:48] "GET /login?__debugger__=yes&cmd=resource&f=jquery.js HTTP/1.1" 200 -
>   127.0.0.1 - - [28/Nov/2019 13:37:48] "GET /login?__debugger__=yes&cmd=resource&f=debugger.js HTTP/1.1" 200 -
>   127.0.0.1 - - [28/Nov/2019 13:37:48] "GET /login?__debugger__=yes&cmd=resource&f=console.png HTTP/1.1" 200 -
>   127.0.0.1 - - [28/Nov/2019 13:37:48] "GET /login?__debugger__=yes&cmd=resource&f=ubuntu.ttf HTTP/1.1" 200 -
>   127.0.0.1 - - [28/Nov/2019 13:37:49] "GET /login?__debugger__=yes&cmd=resource&f=console.png HTTP/1.1" 200 -`
>   How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Why does it not work ?. Can you be more specific ?

Comment: ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1) i have this error msg

Comment: What line giving error? Please post the full stack trace and method signatures of all the written methods involved in the stack trace so that we can help you better.

Comment: have you any idea to help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably are looking for something like this instead:

```
resp = make_response(render_template(*args))
set_access_cookies(resp, access_token)
set_refresh_cookies(resp, refresh_token)               
return resp, 200
```

Comment: if i want redrect URL after render template, how can do it?

Comment: `@app.route('/logout')
def logout():
    signInform = LoginForm()
    resp = jsonify({'logout': True})
    resp = make_response(render_template('login.html', title = 'Login', form =signInform))
    unset_jwt_cookies(resp)
    #redirect(url_for('login'))
    return resp, 200`